# Install Autokey-py3 on Ubuntu 17.04 running Gnome 3

Tags: python, autokey

I have been trying to successful install Autokey-py3 on Ubuntu 17.04 running Gnome 3 for three days.

I have tried the methods described on Github (https://github.com/autokey-py3/autokey) to no avail.

The latest try was using pip (`pip3 install --user git+https://github.com/autokey-py3/autokey`)

That fails with an issue about Failed building wheel for dbus-python.

```
"/usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-xwdht1cv/dbus-python/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-1iefi915-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix=" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-xwdht1cv/dbus-python/
```

Has anyone got any ideas about installing it on Ubuntu. Before switching to attempting installs of the py3 version, I did try the original which ran the gui, but didnt actually seem to work in practice. I have also tried a lot of other methods from searching on the web.

Comment: I installed autokey-gtk on Ubuntu 17.10, but it won't launch because the .Xauthority file doesn't exist in my home directory. I've got to have autokey or downgrade back to 16.04.3.